# How to push the Flask python web application into Pivotal cloud foundry using the private channels to set the anaconda environment?

Tags: python, flask, cloud-foundry

When i try to do use the public channel to push the web app to PCF, it is working.
But when it try to change the channel link to my organization private repository i am able yo push the app to PCF but the issue when trying to view the route is *404 Not Found: Requested route ('conda-test1.cfapps.io') does not exist*.

Is there any format to be maintained for specifying the private repository channels.

Below is my environment.yml and manifest.yml file which is working for public channel:

**environment.yml**

```
name: example-environment

dependencies:

  - python=3.5.6
  - numpy=1.14.0
  - scipy=1.0.0
  - pandas=0.22.0
  - flask=0.12.2

channels:

  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main
  - nodefaults
```

**manifest.yml**

```
--
applications:
 - name: conda-test10
  memory: 1g
  disk_quota: 2GB
  buildpack: python_buildpack
  env: 
   CONDA_SSL_VERIFY: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
```

Comment: You need to include more details. What happens when you try to push your app using your internal channels? Include specific error messages and relevant log output. Please also keep in mind that Pivotal Web Services (I see you're using the cfapps.io domain) is on the public Internet, so any Conda repos you use will need to be accessible from the public Internet. If they are "internal", this may require opening firewall rules or other network changes.

Comment: Thanks for the response. When I try to push the app using private channel, I am able to push the app and also it creates a route. But when i try to access the route, I am getting 404 route not found error. I think bcoz of  public domain I used,  the route is not mapped to my app which is trying to use private conda repository

Comment: If you get `404 Not Found: Requested route ('conda-test1.cfapps.io') does not exist` then your app is not running. This message comes from the Gorouter and is saying that it does not know of any app associated with the route requested.

Comment: But even when I get 404 route not found error, I could see that the app is in started status also route get created once it is pushed to PCF. So my guess is to change the domain and try to push the app and the map the route to the respective app. Please correct me if my understanding is wrong. Thanks again

Comment: The 404 means that route is not mapped to an app or the app it's mapped to is not running, so yes if your app is running it could be that you haven't mapped a route or the route mapped is not what you're trying to access. I'm just guessing though. The bottom line is you need to post more details, like the output from `cf push`, before anyone can really help.

Comment: Thanks Daniel for your help. As you said, the issue was with firewall. Once it is changed, it is working now !! Thanks again